# jQuery circle menu navigation creating tiny circle after toggle close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I click on the main circle the surrounding 5 circles will get minimized completely( to 100% hide), but those are not minimizing completely. There is a small circle over the main circle after minimizing. How to completely minimize (hide) the tiny circle on top of the main circle after toggle close.

I have tried jQuery hide but it was hiding entire element,

Below is the jQuery code,

```
var nbOptions = 8;
var angleStart = -360;

// jquery rotate animation
function rotate(li,d) {
    $({d:angleStart}).animate({d:d}, {
        step: function(now) {
            $(li)
               .css({ transform: 'rotate('+now+'deg)' })
               .find('label')
                  .css({ transform: 'rotate('+(-now)+'deg)' });
        }, duration: 0
    });
}

// show / hide the options
function toggleOptions(s) {
    $(s).toggleClass('open');
    var li = $(s).find('li');
    var deg = $(s).hasClass('half') ? 180/(li.length-1) : 360/li.length;
    for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
        var d = $(s).hasClass('half') ? (i*deg)-90 : i*deg;
        $(s).hasClass('open') ? rotate(li[i],d) : rotate(li[i],angleStart);

    }
}

$('.selector button').click(function(e) {
    toggleOptions($(this).parent());
});

setTimeout(function() { toggleOptions('.selector'); }, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/2574/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in your CSS `.selector li input + label` rule.  You still have some `padding` and `border` width in this rule which is giving the circles some size.  Change those 2 values to 0 and they should completely hide:

```
.selector li input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 120%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  margin-left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;

  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;

  border:0 solid #999; /* previously 1px */
  padding:0; /* previously 6px */
  background:#eee;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out, color 0.1s, background 0.1s;
}
```

**Update:**
Since the `padding` and `border` are needed, you can adjust your ruleset to have these values while the menu circles have the `open` class and remove them when the class is not present

http://jsfiddle.net/avt0fvk4/

Comment: If  I remove the padding then circles won't look like what I expected. I need the padding to the circles (padding around the image circle).

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an updated fiddle with adjusted rules to maintain the `padding` and `border` while the menu items are open

Answer (score 0):

You do need to remove the `border` and `padding` inside `.selector.open li input + label` but you can toggle on and off with another class.

```
.open1 {
    padding: 6px;
    border:1px solid #999;
 }
```

Add this JS:

```
function toggleOptions(s) {
    $(s).toggleClass('open');
    var li = $(s).find('li');
    li.find("label").toggleClass("open1"); // NEW
    ...
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/2576/

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the mini circle is caused by extra padding at wrong class, I have moved the padding to the selector.open. Now it is not showing any mini circle.

```
.selector li input + label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 120%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
   background:#eee;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out, color 0.1s, background 0.1s;
}

.selector li input + label img {    
border-radius:50%;
}

.selector.open li input + label {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  padding:6px;
   border:1px solid #999;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
}

.selector.open li input + label:hover {    
border:1px solid #fff;
padding:6px;
background:#fff;
}
.mainimage{
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

Working code

http://jsfiddle.net/adzFe/2577/